# Is there a way to view the Kubernetes image download progress during pod initialization?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to obtain log information about what is happening with Kubernetes after creating a pod.  The `kubectl get pods` only provides a basic status message. In the case of downloading a large image this can take time and the `kubectl log` command does not provide any real information at this point.  This command seems to only provide information when the container is running.

Is there a way to obtain more log information about the current state of a  Kubernetes pod.  Calling `docker pull` directly provides download status information, but that isn't obvious in Kubernetes.

Comment: do you find any solution since ?

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, Kubernetes doesn't currently expose the progress of `docker pull`. I think your best bet is to look at /var/log/docker.log on the machine that the pod got scheduled onto.

Answer (score 10):

To add to previous answer, if your using a modern worker with systemd you will probably not have a `/var/log/docker.log` file at all.

You can see if downloads are active (on ubuntu/conjure-up) by:

- running bandwidth monitoring tools like `bmon` on the worker (or its hypervisor)
- check download file progress on the worker: `du -s /var/lib/docker/tmp`
- check systemd logs: `journalctl --unit docker`
- Once download is complete, files will be removed from tmp dir

If you see messages like: `Handler for GET /v1.26/images/docker.io/XXX/XXX:latest/json returned error: No such image: docker.io/XXX/XXX:latest` - then I think this means that the image isn't available and will be downloaded, not that it doesn't exist remotely ;-)

Answer (score 3):

After https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/91563 is merged, Starting from kubernetes v1.19, image pull time can be seen in event

You can use `kubectl describe po` to view the event of a pod:

```
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  17m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned org1/org1-5d68c7cdfc-4vr95 to fabric-example-test-worker
  Normal  Pulling    17m   kubelet            Pulling image "hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest"
  Normal  Pulled     16m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest" in 37.97291039s
  Normal  Created    16m   kubelet            Created container init
  Normal  Started    16m   kubelet            Started container init
  Normal  Pulling    16m   kubelet            Pulling image "hyperledgerk8s/fabric-ca:iam-20230131"
  Normal  Pulled     15m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "hyperledgerk8s/fabric-ca:iam-20230131" in 32.879149587s
  Normal  Created    15m   kubelet            Created container ca
  Normal  Started    15m   kubelet            Started container ca
```

you can see event like `Successfully pulled image "<image-name>" in <pull-time>`.

Depending on the kubernetes version you used, you may see different but similar events:

- `Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 49.657983991s`   [pr first in kubernetes v1.19](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/91563)
- `Successfully pulled image "docker.m.daocloud.io/library/ubuntu:22.10" in 49.18401355s(72.871704s including waiting)`  [pr first in kubernetes v1.26](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/111772)

You can use `kubectl get event -A -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.reason == "Pulled")|.message' | grep -v "already present on machine" | sort -u` to show all images pulling time in the cluster:

```
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/bff-server:v0.1.0-20221223\" in 1m8.253531475s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/capsule:v0.1.2-20221122\" in 1m26.683960885s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/cert-manager-cainjector:v1.8.0\" in 51.586788227s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/cert-manager-controller:v1.8.0\" in 1m9.70810772s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/cert-manager-webhook:v1.8.0\" in 58.537515016s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/iam-provider:v0.1.0-20221223\" in 22.156470994s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/ingress-nginx-controller:v1.3.0\" in 1m1.517984838s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/kube-oidc-proxy:v0.3.0-20221008\" in 17.411147568s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/oidc-server:v0.1.0-20220923\" in 1m6.740135374s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hub.tenxcloud.com/u4a-component/resource-viewer:v0.1.0-20221024\" in 8.324246263s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/fabric-ca:iam-20230131\" in 31.555210343s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/fabric-ca:iam-20230131\" in 32.879149587s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/fabric-ca:iam-20230131\" in 7.424359703s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/fabric-orderer:2.4.7\" in 1.892604297s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/fabric-orderer:2.4.7\" in 18.928304737s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/fabric-orderer:2.4.7\" in 30.371704319s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/grpc-web:latest\" in 1.841436782s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/grpc-web:latest\" in 1m15.674570039s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/iam-provider:fabric\" in 23.055525242s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest\" in 1.822674163s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest\" in 1.85105156s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest\" in 1.880725516s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest\" in 1.892004186s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest\" in 28.981166252s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest\" in 30.921652345s"
"Successfully pulled image \"hyperledgerk8s/ubi-minimal:latest\" in 37.97291039s"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a possible way to do that which is by downloading the images first then deploying Nginx.

- For **minikube** users you can run:

```sh
minikube image load <image-name>
```

- For **Kind** users which is my case:

```sh
kind load docker-image <image-name> --name k8s-cluster
```

this way you can track image pulling by cluster, this at least help you know image download progress.

Comment: same as Erdogan, the question is generic and your answer is very specific to your use case. So that does not solve the question but rather show a workaround for minikube and kind A comment on the original question is enough in such a case i guess

Answer (score -2):

I'm using Docker Desktop for local Kubernetes testing, so when I run `docker pull <image>`, it shows the current progress.

Comment: the question is generic and your answer is very specific to your use case. So that does not solve the question but rather show a workaround for Docker desktop